# Generating samples with Sobol sequence in python

Tags: python, sample

I need to generate 5000 samples with 10 variables with the sobol sequence. I have limits for the variables. Like this: [[500, 0.1,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5],[1500, 0.9,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5]]

I have tried this way:

```
import chaospy as cp

ndim = 5000
lower_bound = [500, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
upper_bound = [1500, 0.9, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5]

uniform_distributions = [cp.Uniform(lower_bound[i], upper_bound[i]) for i in range(ndim)]

sampler = cp.sampler.sobol(qr_input=True, dim=ndim)

joint_distribution = cp.J(*uniform_distributions)

samples = sampler.sample(5000, joint_distribution)

print(samples)
```

But its notworking. Can someone help me with this sample generation?

I am getting the error:

```
cp.sampler.sobol(qr_input=True, dim=ndim) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error? Is the distribution on uniform enough, is it too uniform?

Comment: Appear this error:  sampler = cp.sampler.sobol(qr_input=True, dim=ndim)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable